# SQL: Is there any way to use Order By on an update statement?

Tags: sql, sql-update

I need to update one record only in a database, and assign it to a user. Here is what I am doing:

```
UPDATE TOP (1) books SET assigneduser = 1
WHERE bookstatus = 7
AND ((assigneduser is null) or (assigneduser = 1));
```

I also have a field named bookname which I would prefer to order by, but update does not seem to support it.

Also note that I will have 50 users using the software at once, so I will need to ensure that only one user is assigned a book. Otherwise I would run a select first and then an update on the top record.

Thanks.

Comment: Would you mind letting us know what RDBMS you are using?

Answer (score 2):

You have to first select the desired record, then update it:

```
update books
    set assigneduser = 1
where BookPrimaryKeyField = (
    SELETE TOP 1 BookPrimaryKeyField
    from books
    WHERE bookstatus = 7
    AND ((assigneduser is null) or (assigneduser = 1));
)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to update only one row in the database the best way to do it is to find out what is its primary key and use it. You can do that by saying

```
UPDATE books SET assigneduser = 1
WHERE BOOKID 
= (SELECT top 1 BOOKID FROM books where
 bookstatus = 7
AND ((assigneduser is null) or (assigneduser = 1)));
```

Comment: @Adrian - I don't think so, I removed it from my sql, it was a remnant from copy'n'paste - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since update doesn't return any data and 'order by' sorts a result set, there is nothing for `ORDER BY` to work on, and what you seek cannot be done.

If you want to assign only one book you could update using a join on top 1 from you set.

```
UPDATE b0 SET assigneduser = 1
FROM b0 
  INNER JOIN
(SELECT top 1 id FROM books
WHERE user = 1 OR user is null
AND status =7)  b1 ON b1.id = b0.id
```

or perhaps less cryptic

```
UPDATE user SET assigneduser = 1
WHERE id IN
(SELECT top 1 id FROM books
WHERE user = 1 OR user is null
AND status =7)  b1 ON b1.id = b0.id
```

Whether that strategy is robust regarding concurrency is a matter of transaction semantics.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE B
SET assigneduser = 1
FROM books B
WHERE bookstatus = 7
AND ((assigneduser is null) or (assigneduser = 1))
and bookid = (select min(bookid) from books where assigneuser is null)
```

I assumed you had an ID column bookid.

This gets you the lowest book id with no user assigned, and joins it back to books to give you a single record (as part of b) which you can then update.

Answer (score 0):

Look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177523.aspx.

If you must use TOP to apply updates in a meaningful chronology, you must use TOP together with ORDER BY in a subselect statement. The following example updates the vacation hours of the 10 employees with the earliest hire dates.

```
UPDATE HumanResources.Employee
SET VacationHours = VacationHours + 8
FROM (SELECT TOP 10 BusinessEntityID FROM HumanResources.Employee
     ORDER BY HireDate ASC) AS th
WHERE HumanResources.Employee.BusinessEntityID = th.BusinessEntityID;
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

It would probably be easier to break this into 2 pieces

```
    DECLARE @bookid as INT

    SELECT TOP (1) @bookid = id FROM books
    WHERE bookstatus = 7
    AND ((assigneduser is null) or (assigneduser = 1))
    ORDER BY bookname

    UPDATE books SET assigneduser = 1
    WHERE id = @bookid
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to get around it by using a subquery as following:

```
UPDATE books SET assigneduser=1
AND ((assigneduser is null) or (assigneduser = 1))
AND bookname in (SELECT TOP 1 bookname FROM Table ORDER BY bookname DESC)
```

Comment: @Adrian: Just for curiosity - what do you think is wrong with `UPDATE TOP(1)` ? It seems to work for me (assuming it's SQLServer)

Comment: @a1ex07, it would depend on which version of which database you are using whether it would work.

Comment: It also works for me in SQL Server 2008. OP did not specify RDMS though. It's risky to state it works. That's why I asked 'are you sure', instead of 'that's wrong'. BTW, I don't know if it would work on SQL Server 2005 or less

Comment: @Adrian: Yeah, I see... I don't have SQLServer 2005, but according to msdn it should also work. Anyway, what you are saying makes perfect sense - it may not work in older versions or on different RDMS.

Comment: There you have it, guys. Also, when you use `TOP`, order is important, which is what OP is asking: how to make sure you're updating the right record? My answer does that, in an ANSI SQL fashion, BTW.